# SNMPd opens "random" UDP port besides 161 and 162 to the outside

Tags: snmp, snmpd

I would like to use snmp to monitor my localhost and have installed the corresponding package on Ubuntu 18.03 with `apt install snmp`. Without having changed the default configuration, I have launched the daemon with `systemctl start snmpd`. After launching the daemon the output of `lsof -i -n | grep snmpd` is as follows:

```
snmpd     14668     Debian-snmp   12u  IPv4 13252990      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:snmp 
snmpd     14668     Debian-snmp   13u  IPv4 13252988      0t0  UDP *:41898
```

I am wondering about the second line of the output as the port has been opened to the outside. Restarting the daemon changes the open port to another (randomized?) high port number. I have been looking up this behaviour a couple of hours and wasn´t able to find any explanation.

**Can anybody explain to me whats going on here or how to disable/remove the open port?**

---

### Configuration

AgentAdress is configured as follows:

```
# /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

# Listen for connections from the local system only
agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161
```

The daemon has been launched with following options:

```
# /etc/default/snmp

# snmpd options (use syslog, close stdin/out/err).
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid'
```

Output of `ps aux | grep snmpd`

```
/usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux mteTrigger mteTriggerConf -f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if anybody comes across the same question: The UDP port has been opened by snmp-traps. In order to avoid this behavior, I had to comment out following line in the snmpd.conf:

```
/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

#  ACTIVE MONITORING
                                    #   send SNMPv1  traps
# !comment this line out!
# trapsink     localhost public
```

Read this link for further information: https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/mailman/message/29219475/